# Clone a String for an async move closure in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream, future

Is there any way I can clone values for the `async move` closures for `futures::stream`?

I'm using future's [`for_each_concurrent`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each_concurrent)

My code is something like this:

```rust
async fn foo() {
    use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

    let a: String = String::new();

    let stream = stream::once(async { 42 });

    stream
        .for_each_concurrent(None, |stream_item| async move {
            println!("{}", a);
            println!("{}", stream_item);
        })
        .await;
}
```

The error here:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:9:61
   |
4  |       let a: String = String::new();
   |           - captured outer variable
...
9  |           .for_each_concurrent(None, |stream_item| async move {
   |  _____________________________________________________________^
10 | |             println!("{}", a);
   | |                            -
   | |                            |
   | |                            move occurs because `a` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   | |                            move occurs due to use in generator
11 | |             println!("{}", stream_item);
12 | |         })
   | |_________^ move out of `a` occurs here
```

I have to use `move` because of this:

```
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `stream_item`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:9:56
   |
9  |           .for_each_concurrent(None, |stream_item| async {
   |  ________________________________________________________^
10 | |             println!("{}", a);
11 | |             println!("{}", stream_item);
   | |                            ----------- `stream_item` is borrowed here
12 | |         })
   | |_________^ may outlive borrowed value `stream_item`
```

If it was a loop I'd just clone `a`s in each iteration, and move those clones inside a closure, is there a way to do something like this here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply clone `a` before the `async move` block:

```rust
stream
    .for_each_concurrent(None, |stream_item| {
        let a = a.clone();
        async move {
            println!("{}", a);
            println!("{}", stream_item);
        }
    })
    .await;
```