# Using Tokio sender with for_each_concurrent closure

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

i am having a very hard time figuring out how to get messages consumed from a tokio `mpsc::channel` to run concurrently.  my current approach is to call `into_stream()` on the `recv()` call, then call `for_each_concurrent` on this wrapped object.  as i understand it, this should execute the code concurrently as the messages come in, rather than in sequence (as when you use `recv()`).

the sample below omits irrelevant details, but the general idea should be fairly easy to see.

```rust
let upload_id = s3_response.upload_id.unwrap();
let _ = rxu.recv().into_stream().for_each_concurrent(10, |part| async move {
    let txb1 = txb.clone();
    match part {
        Some((path, part_number)) => {
            let opts = options();
                         //  ...
                    let _ = fs::remove_file(path);
                    let _ = txb1.send((completed_part, upload_id.clone())).await;
                    log::info!("Finished uploading part: {}", part_number);
                }
                None => {
                    log::info!("Finished uploading part files");
                }
            }
        });
```

this results in compiler errors suggesting that things (`upload_id` and `txb`) can't be moved in to the `FnMut` closure.  i've tried all sorts of approaches suggested for these problems more generally and none seem to work with this specific situation.  am i missing something major here?  example error is below.

```rust
          let upload_id = s3_response.upload_id.unwrap();
    |                --------- captured outer variable
...
131 |            let _ = rxu.recv().into_stream().for_each_concurrent(10, |part| async move {
    |  ___________________________________________________________________-_________________^
    | | __________________________________________________________________|
    | ||
132 | ||             let uid = upload_id.clone();
    | ||                       ---------
    | ||                       |
    | ||                       move occurs because `upload_id` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    | ||                       move occurs due to use in generator
133 | ||             let txb1 = txb.clone();
134 | ||             match part {
...   ||
161 | ||             }
162 | ||         });
    | ||         ^
    | ||_________|
    | |__________captured by this `FnMut` closure
    |            move out of `upload_id` occurs here

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `txb`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/lib.rs:131:84
    |
45  |        let (txb, mut rxb) = mpsc::channel(1); // builder channel
    |             --- captured outer variable
...
131 |            let _ = rxu.recv().into_stream().for_each_concurrent(10, |part| async move {
    |  ___________________________________________________________________-_________________^
    | | __________________________________________________________________|
    | ||
132 | ||             let uid = upload_id.clone();
133 | ||             let txb1 = txb.clone();
    | ||                        ---
    | ||                        |
    | ||                        move occurs because `txb` has type `tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<(CompletedPart, String)>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    | ||                        move occurs due to use in generator
134 | ||             match part {
...   ||
161 | ||             }
162 | ||         });
    | ||         ^
    | ||_________|
    | |__________captured by this `FnMut` closure
    |            move out of `txb` occurs here
```

any help is much appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to do the cloning outside of the closure ?

Comment: I have, yes. I've also tried clones of clones and all sorts of other permutations of cloning things.  it always seems to blow up as soon as anything (either the original ```Sender``` or ```String``` or any of its clones) moves into that async ```FnMut``` closure, regardless of where i actually clone it.

Comment: That's weird, I see this question which seems similar, and was solutioned just by performing cloning before the closure declaration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429545/clone-a-string-for-an-async-move-closure-in-rust

Comment: That's one I hadn't tried, and it worked!  I didn't consider that you could put anything between the ```|part``` and ```async move``` block.  very cool.. thanks!